# What's scroll performance of MacBook Retina on RubyMine, Eclipse and Netbeans IDEs?

Tags: macbook-pro, ide

can someone who owns a Retina MacBook Pro tell me how the rMBP performs in current IDEs like RubyMine, Eclipse or Netbeans? I am worried that it cannot handle long text / source files very well when scolling. Videos welcome.

Cheers

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “cannot handle long text / source files very well when scrolling”?

Comment: The first time I played with the rMBP I noticed some stuttering when scrolling in applications, like in Safari for example, that had an awful performance on Lion when scrolling web pages. "cannot handle" means cannot gaurantee a smooth experience. My question is whether it will be stuttering when scolling long text files in eclipse or RubyMine on a rMBP (base model) or not.

Comment: Sounds like swapping.  You generally want as much memory as you can afford.

Comment: No no, it is not about swapping. What I mean is graphics performance.

Answer (score 1):

I work for about a week with rMBP 15" and RubyMine, and I can't see any stuttering in any application, not just RubyMine, Sublime etc...